# How to audit "all file failures" on a system partition from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, security, batch

Directly from the source:

> Open Windows Explorer and use the file and folder properties function
>   to verify that the audit settings on each partition/drive is
>   configured to audit all "failures" for the "Everyone" group

How could you configure windows to do this via command line?

I have tried a utility called auditpol, although it doesn't appear to do what I require

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?